# Does google adwords de-dupe conversions?

Tags: google-ads-api, deduplication

I'm using AdWords to track conversions on an ajax site. It works well for single conversions that have a unique label and value.

**The Problem:**

On the site I have a use case where a user can fire multiple very similar looking conversions in short succession. Sometimes these conversions are unique, sometimes they could match one or more of the other conversion values and labels.

When I submit these conversions, it tracks some of them, and not others.

At first, I was adding the conversion snippet to the page, so I figured it was including conversions.js only once, and not firing the others. So, to fix that, I moved the conversion snippet to an iFrame and put that on the page. That had the same problem, but was definitely including conversions.js. I was worried that the problem may have to do with the fact that they're fired in quick succession, so I made them wait before firing the next. I tried intervals of 1,2, and 4 seconds, none of which solved the issue.

In an attempt to figure out what was going wrong, I beautified conversions.js, and found a debug option. I turned it on, and it was warning on all conversions about a missing conversion_id - I tried adding google_conversion_id, and just set it to a timestamp, so it would always be unique. This didn't solve the problem either.

I finally tried just ditching the iFrames, and adding the tracking pixel to the page. The tracking pixel still fires the conversions just fine, and seems to add an iFrame to the page, then delete it. Unfortunately, the conversions still are missing.

**The Question:**

In light of this not working in any of many different ways, I'm wondering if google is de-duping my similar conversions. The docs have no information that shed light on this, but they also don't document the google_conversion_id, so there's plenty going on that isn't documented.

If they are, why wouldn't google_conversion_id fix this? It seems that should unique each lead. I can't append to the label or value, and I'm making all my requests with a cachebuster appended to the end to make sure it's not on the browser end. I can verify that it's working, as either conversions.js gets included or the iFrame shows up.

Any ideas? Anyone know where I can ask a googler about this? It's driving me CRAZY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `google_conversion_id` is your account number. Do not change it, or things just won't work.

As far as I can tell there is no way to pass a unique transaction ID, nor to sign the conversion parameters to prevent duplicates and request forgeries.

Google has no way to differentiate the following scenarios, because they result in exactly the same set of calls to the current Google adWords conversion script:

- A customer buying two widgets at $50 in quick succession
- A customer buying one widget at $50 and refreshing or returning to your receipt page
- An evil adSense user triggering your conversion pixel to log himself two $50 sales

This was merely annoying when they only supported CPC, but with CPA it has become a vulnerability in the Google adWords system.

Comment: The solution I ended up using was to create 5 different labels, and cycle through them every time a conversion of that type was fired. It's a hack, but it finally worked.